# easily migrate wordpress database from local to production

Tags: php, mysql, database, wordpress

I find myself constantly doing this routine to migrate a wordpress database to staging or production servers:

1. doing a SQL dump of the local wordpress database
2. open the .SQL file then search and replace all "localhost:9999" with "mysite.com"
3. import modified .SQL to production database

I find this very cumbersome. Is there a more simple way to do this? I'm hoping there's something equally simple as pushing changed files under version control?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a great article on WordPress.org about moving a WP project.  Specifically, there is a very handy search and replace tool (discussed in the article) that will more easily do what you're after.

**Article:**
http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress

**Search and Replace Tool:**
http://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/

I build a lot of WP sites and this method has worked seamlessly for me every time.  The search and replace tool is a go-to utility for me.