# WordPress transfer on existing WordPress on another domain

Tags: wordpress, file-transfer, database-migration, data-transfer

A client wanted me to create a new WordPress theme on our server and once completed he would like me to transfer it on his existing WordPress installation. What would be the best way to do this?

Comment: Did you try http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [easily migrate wordpress database from local to production](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15796525/easily-migrate-wordpress-database-from-local-to-production)

Answer (score 0):

[Seriously?](http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress)
[Did](http://wp.smashingmagazine.com/2013/04/08/moving-wordpress-website/)
[you](http://blog.triphp.com/how-to/how-to-move-wordpress-to-a-new-server-or-host.html)
[even](http://www.craniumstorm.com/how-to-move-a-wordpress-site/)
[try](http://www.siteground.com/tutorials/wordpress/transfer-wordpress.htm)
[using](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/3-plugins-for-easily-migrating-a-wordpress-site-tried-tested/)
[Google?](http://www.sitepoint.com/move-wordpress-new-server-without-losing-anything/)
[Or just running a simple StackOverflow search?](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=migrate+wordpress)